# forcing ndiff on very dissimilar strings

Tags: python, difflib

The `ndiff` function from `difflib` allows a nice interface to detect differences in lines. It does a great job when the lines are close enough:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(list(ndiff(['foo*'], ['foot'], )))
- foo*
?    ^

+ foot
?    ^
```

But when the lines are too dissimilar, the rich reporting is no longer possible:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(list(ndiff(['foo'], ['foo*****'], )))
- foo
+ foo*****
```

This is the use case I am hitting, and I am trying to find ways to use `ndiff` (or the underlying class `Differ`) to force the reporting even if the strings are too dissimilar.

For the failing example, I would like to have a result like:

```
>>> print '\n'.join(list(ndiff(['foo'], ['foo*****'], )))
- foo
+ foo*****
?    +++++
```

Comment: from a quick look, maybe `unified_diff` is a better choice here?

Comment: `unified_diff` behaves the same as ndiff when the strings are too dissimilar

Comment: this looks like something in there is choosing compactness - e.g. if you do something like `ndiff(['foo fighters unite'], ['food fighters'])`, which has about the same amount of difference, it prints what you want. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function responsible for printing the context (i.e. those lines starting with `?`) is [`Differ._fancy_replace`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/difflib.py#L928). That function works by checking whether the two lines are equal by at least 75% (see the `cutoff` variable). Unfortunately, that 75% cutoff is hard-coded and cannot be changed.

What I can suggest is to subclass `Differ` and provide a version of `_fancy_replace` that simply ignores the cutoff. Here it is:

```
from difflib import Differ, SequenceMatcher

class FullContextDiffer(Differ):

    def _fancy_replace(self, a, alo, ahi, b, blo, bhi):
        """
        Copied and adapted from https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/difflib.py#L928
        """
        best_ratio = 0
        cruncher = SequenceMatcher(self.charjunk)

        for j in range(blo, bhi):
            bj = b[j]
            cruncher.set_seq2(bj)
            for i in range(alo, ahi):
                ai = a[i]
                if ai == bj:
                    continue
                cruncher.set_seq1(ai)
                if cruncher.real_quick_ratio() > best_ratio and \
                      cruncher.quick_ratio() > best_ratio and \
                      cruncher.ratio() > best_ratio:
                    best_ratio, best_i, best_j = cruncher.ratio(), i, j

        yield from self._fancy_helper(a, alo, best_i, b, blo, best_j)

        aelt, belt = a[best_i], b[best_j]

        atags = btags = ""
        cruncher.set_seqs(aelt, belt)
        for tag, ai1, ai2, bj1, bj2 in cruncher.get_opcodes():
            la, lb = ai2 - ai1, bj2 - bj1
            if tag == 'replace':
                atags += '^' * la
                btags += '^' * lb
            elif tag == 'delete':
                atags += '-' * la
            elif tag == 'insert':
                btags += '+' * lb
            elif tag == 'equal':
                atags += ' ' * la
                btags += ' ' * lb
            else:
                raise ValueError('unknown tag %r' % (tag,))
        yield from self._qformat(aelt, belt, atags, btags)

        yield from self._fancy_helper(a, best_i+1, ahi, b, best_j+1, bhi)
```

And here is an example of how it works:

```
a = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'foobar',
]

b = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'barfoo',
]

print('\n'.join(FullContextDiffer().compare(a, b)))

# Output:
# 
#   foo
#   bar
# - foobar
# ?    ---
# 
# + barfoo
# ? +++
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want to do here is not to compare across multiple lines, but across strings. You can then pass your strings directly, without a list, and you should get a behaviour close to the one you are looking for.

```
>>> print ('\n'.join(list(ndiff('foo', 'foo*****'))))
  f
  o
  o
+ *
+ *
+ *
+ *
+ *
```

Even though the output format is not the exact one you are looking for, it encapsulate the correct information. We can make an output adapter to give the correct format.

```
def adapter(out):
    chars = []
    symbols = []

    for c in out:
        chars.append(c[2])
        symbols.append(c[0])

    return ''.join(chars), ''.join(symbols)
```

This can be used like so.

```
>>> print ('\n'.join(adapter(ndiff('foo', 'foo*****'))))
foo*****
   +++++
```